# Given angles and area, how to find sides of a spherical triangle?

Tags: spherical-geometry, spherical-trigonometry

So, given angles and area, how to find the sides of a spherical triangle?

I only know that the angles uniquely determine the sides, but what is the relation?

Answer (score 1):

For angles A, B, and C and corresponding sides a, b, and c of a spherical triangle:

cos A = -cos B cos C + sin B sin C cos a

cos B = -cos C cos A + sin C sin A cos b

cos C = -cos A cos B + sin A sin B cos c

Just plug in your numbers and solve for the sides.